# Cannot access to mongodb from container app

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I setting up a project using docker, nodejs and mongodb. Here is my configuration: https://github.com/tuanna2704/docker-express/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

after I run

```
docker-compose up
```

And I can access to http://localhost:4000 via my real machine but application cannot access to db container. Im newbie docker. Any one can explain for me reason why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: provide your application logs `docker logs container-id`

Answer (score 0):

- Check mongo client `mongodb://localhost:27017/` working status after
  `docker-compose up` in your local machine; If it works, then `mongodb://mongo:27017/` should be fine
- Better add tags in the image name `image: mongo:latest`